# Java- Issue with try-catch exception inside custom exception

Tags: java, exception, custom-exceptions

I have a custom Java exception class, `CustomRestException`:

```
 import org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject;

 public class CustomRestException extends Exception{

    private String httpStatusMessage;    
    private Integer httpStatusCode;

    private String endpointBody;
    private String callType;        
    private List<HashMap<String,String>> headerParams;
    private List<HashMap<String,String>> queryParams;

    private JSONObject endPointErrorResponse;   

    public CustomRestException (RestCallParameters p,String type,String url,String body,UniformInterfaceException ue) {

       super(p.getCollectionErrMsg());      
       this.endpointBody= body;
       this.endPointUrl = url;
       this.callType = type;
       setUniformInterfaceExceptionParameters(ue);
    }

    private void setUniformInterfaceExceptionParameters(UniformInterfaceException ue) {
        try {
            this.httpStatusMessage = ue.getMessage();    
            this.httpStatusMessage  = ue.getResponse().getClientResponseStatus().toString();
            this.httpStatusCode = ue.getResponse().getStatus();

            this.endPointErrorResponse =
                    new JSONObject(ue.getResponse().getEntity(String.class));            
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
             LOGGER.info("[setUniformInterfaceExceptionParameters]  Ecnountered error ",ex);
        }
    }
}
```

I am throwing this CustomRestException from a method:

```
public String myMethod() throws CustomRestException {
   try{
       //make some rest call here
   }catch(UniformInterfaceException ue){
       throw new CustomRestException (p,"POST",url,p.getReqBody(),ue);   
   }
}
```

then, I am catching this `CustomRestException` somewhere else:

```
public Response myEndPointMethod(){
    try{
        //some code
        myClassObj.myMethod();     //calling myMethod() above
        //some code

    } catch (CustomRestException e) {             
       LOGGER.error("(someMessage) CustomRestException ", e);       
    }
```

*My problem*

```
this.endPointErrorResponse = new JSONObject(ue.getResponse().getEntity(String.class));
```

If this line throws any exception (I have seen only `JSONException` so far), the program terminates after executing this logger in the catch block:

```
LOGGER.info("[setUniformInterfaceExceptionParameters]  Ecnountered error ",ex);
```

*My Expectation*

 The logger `LOGGER.error("(someMessage) CustomRestException ", e);` in `myEndPointMethod()` should be called.

Are we not supposed to handle  (try-catch) exceptions inside custom exceptions?

Any idea where I am going wrong?

Comment: "the program terminates after executing the Logger in the catch block": You have two such catch blocks in your code snippets, which one are you referring to? Is the program terminating before the `CustomRestException` is thrown?

Comment: In what kind of application is the code being run?

Comment: somewhere the `CustomRestException` is being created (to enter that code) and almost sure it is being `throw`n - so perhaps this is causing the program to terminate.... and I would handle that Exception in my Exception - would kind of confusing if one Exception is thrown while creating another one (probably more relevant than the first one)  - or better avoid that case at all: somehow I feel  this is an indication that something else should have been checked before...

Comment: BW: (custom) Exceptions are normally very simple, almost empty...

Comment: I think there is no issue throwing and catching an exception (and handling it) within a custom exception. Program does not terminate after handling an exception in a catch-block (unless you have code to terminate the program in that block).

Comment: Putting together the error response really doesn't belong inside an exception like this. This exception is doing too much work.

Comment: You need to provide more information because the behavior you describe is not explained by the code provided.

Comment: @harogaston.Are you saying, with the given code, my expectation is correct?
I have put up almost all the relevant code I can think of.Rest is mostly business logic.

Comment: When you say `the program terminates` you mean the application shuts down?

Comment: Its a HTTP endpoint exposed by the JAVA API.The endpoint fails with internal error(status 500). And the only log entry is "[setUniformInterfaceExceptionParameters]  Ecnountered error"
Since the exception is handled, i think the log entry "(someMessage) CustomRestException " should also be there.